# How to install FLTK on MacOS

Tags: c++, fltk

I'm learning to use the FLTK in Bjarne's Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice. However, I'm stuck trying to install fltk-1.1.10 on my macOS (Monterrey 12.4).

When I run the `make` command, I get this error:

```
Makefile:28: makeinclude: No such file or directory
if test -f config.status; then \
                ./config.status --recheck; \
                ./config.status; \
        else \
                ./configure; \
        fi
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** [makeinclude] Error 77
```

Here's the output of the `config.log` file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Tims-Air
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 21.5.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 512 tasks, 2908 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 3.57, Mach factor: 1.15
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
PATH: /Users/akojitimothy/Desktop/chromedriver
PATH: /Users/akojitimothy/Desktop/chromedriver


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2125: checking for gcc
configure:2141: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2152: result: gcc
configure:2390: checking for C compiler version
configure:2397: gcc --version >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
configure:2400: $? = 0
configure:2407: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
configure:2410: $? = 0
configure:2417: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:2420: $? = 1
configure:2443: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2470: gcc  -arch i386   -arch i386 conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd (3 slices)
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:2473: $? = 1
configure:2511: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define __APPLE_QD__ 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2518: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=c++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_set=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
ARCHFLAGS=''
AUDIOLIBS=''
CAT1EXT=''
CAT3EXT=''
CAT6EXT=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=' -arch i386'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='c++'
CXXFLAGS=' -arch i386'
DEFS=''
DSOCOMMAND='echo'
DSOFLAGS=''
DSOLINK=''
DSONAME=''
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FLDSONAME=''
FLLIBBASENAME='libfltk_forms.a'
FLLIBNAME='../lib/libfltk_forms.a'
FLUID='fluid'
FL_API_VERSION='1.1'
FL_MAJOR_VERSION='1'
FL_MINOR_VERSION='1'
FL_PATCH_VERSION='10'
FTCONFIG=''
GLDEMOS='gldemos'
GLDSONAME=''
GLLIB=''
GLLIBBASENAME='libfltk_gl.a'
GLLIBNAME='../lib/libfltk_gl.a'
GREP=''
GROFF=''
HLINKS=''
HTMLDOC=''
IMAGELIBS=''
IMGDSONAME=''
IMGLIBBASENAME='libfltk_images.a'
IMGLIBNAME='../lib/libfltk_images.a'
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_DESKTOP=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
JPEG=''
JPEGINC=''
LARGEFILE=''
LDFLAGS=' -arch i386'
LIBBASENAME='libfltk.a'
LIBCOMMAND=''
LIBEXT='.a'
LIBNAME='../lib/libfltk.a'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LINKFLTK='../lib/libfltk.a'
LINKFLTKFORMS='../lib/libfltk_forms.a'
LINKFLTKGL='../lib/libfltk_gl.a'
LINKFLTKIMG='../lib/libfltk_images.a'
LINKSHARED='../lib/libfltk_images.a ../lib/libfltk_forms.a ../lib/libfltk.a'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEDEPEND=''
NROFF=''
OBJEXT=''
OPTIM=''
OSX_ONLY=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PNG=''
PNGINC=''
POSTBUILD=''
PTHREAD_FLAGS=''
RANLIB=''
SHAREDSUFFIX=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STATICIMAGELIBS=''
THREADS=''
UNINSTALL_DESKTOP=''
XMKMF=''
XPROP=''
X_CFLAGS=''
X_EXTRA_LIBS=''
X_LIBS=''
X_PRE_LIBS=''
ZLIB=''
ZLIBINC=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define __APPLE_QD__ 1

configure: exit 77
```

I've tried reading through it but I can't understand what the issue might be. I've verified that I have both gcc and g++ compilers on my computer and I've tried setting the `CXX` environment variable before running `make` but I still get the same error.

What are the steps I need to follow to compile the source code and install the toolkit? I'm currently using VSCode and I'm using the `run` extension for compiling C++ programs. Here's `my c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include",
                "/Users/akojitimothy/Documents/C++ Projects/Programming Principles Exercises/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-10",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I apologize if this is too much info but I don't understand what might be causing the errors I'm currently getting.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to install at least Xcode and its command line tools. Also, 1.1.4 is *really* outdated and will probably not compile or run on current  macOS. I recommend 1.3.8, but if you want the best macOS support and cmake, FLTK 1.4.0 is not yet released, but very stable and very active.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthiasMelcher. I successfully got it to run by installing Xcode and its CLI tools and then running `brew install fltk`.

Comment: For anyone struggling to configure fltk using Xcode, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGLeX4AyTXw) was really helpful. Note that to get the examples to run, you need to include the fltk-images dynamic library to the project as well.